# Building one project is causing another to be built

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I've got a C# project in my solution. When I try to build it, a different C++ project is being built first. The C++ project is not listed as a project dependency of my C# project, or as a dependency of its dependencies.

And there is no "build only" option for C# projects so I cannot tell if this is a dependency issue, or some weird bug.

Anyone able to help?

Comment: Try increasing the build verbosity to _diagnostic_.  Use _Tools/Options/Projects and Solutions/Build and Run_.

Comment: Pre and post build events can trigger build as well....